# How to use a 'TokenCredential' for Bing Search query on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, bing-api

Getting a `TokenCredential` (from namespace `Azure.Core`) associated to a registered app is the way to go to gain access to most services on Azure, if the `Access control (IAM)` is properly setup up front.

How to do that with a [Bing Search service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/reference/headers)? The examples that I can find only illustrates the raw API key approach.